# odd edit behavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, revisions-list

A user submitted an edit for his post with the comment "edited tags":

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6528592/revisions

But it looks like nothing at all changed:

[image: Nothing changed, but there's a change]

([c](/questions/tagged/c) and [concurrency](/questions/tagged/concurrency) were there with the first version of the post.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user added some tags, then edited again to remove the new tags.  Because this was done in the 5 minute "quick edit" window, it appears as if nothing changed.

We'll look at just destroying the null edit in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

We've since revised our [solution here from Jarrod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96960/odd-edit-behavior/96968#96968) due to exploits as [explained elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history). Now, any null edits of this sort will instead be an empty revision but explicitly state "Edit removed during grace period".