# Why was I notified twice of a single edit?

Tags: support, edits, notifications, global-inbox

In reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10342212/revisions), I received two notifications that my post was edit, but there was only one edit in the revision history. However, there was a noticeable difference in the notifications, that the title had been changed (old on bottom, new on top).

[image: Notice the very minor title change.]

So why did I get notified twice that my *answer* was edited? My answer was clearly edited only once, yet it seems that I got a second notification indicating the question was also edited, but the notification doesn't actually say the question itself was edited? Is there some sort of bug that duplicates the notification if the question and answer are both edited close together?

Comment: Which post? That is a link to the image....

Comment: I guess the change in the title of the _question_ confused the system.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Hah, I had typed the `[1]` there for the link thinking I'd add it at the end, then saw the `[1]` was already there, but it was the image, so I never added the post's link. -.-

Comment: @animuson lol oy...

Comment: I wonder if he edited it twice within the editing window, generating one revision but two notifications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oops, sorry about that. I was screwing around with [the "feature" that silently destroys a revision when you undo an edit within the 5-minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history) again. I really ought to stop doing that.

But seriously: I edited your answer, decided I didn't like my edit, undid it, then came back a few seconds later to put it back in. Apparently, that causes two notifications to be generated.

And no, it has nothing to do with the question title being edited between edits. I should say, though, that I tend to hop back and forth between question and answer when making edits to both. Again, that's entirely my doing, not a fault in the system.

Comment: Well then, perhaps it should be a [meta-tag:feature-request] to have the notification destroyed when the revision is destroyed?

Comment: @animuson: Perhaps. Notifications have been known to be generated and left pending even when the events no longer apply (e.g. you gain a privilege and lose it later, or you receive a reply and the comment gets deleted later).

Comment: I would make feature request asking to avoid having "your post has been edited" notification when there is still such notification unread in the inbox. Should be simple to implement as far as I can tell. :)