# Replace "closed" with "duplicate" in search results

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[[duplicate] recently replaced [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate) in question titles in question lists, but not in search results:

[image]

Comment: Even I can't tell a question list from a search result. Sorry about the premature status retag. Also, this marks my first [Edit removed during grace period] ever after literally *dozens* of [silent grace-period edit removals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137165/why-was-i-notified-twice-of-a-single-edit/137173#137173) throughout the network.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn for shame, and hear we thought you were perfect, being a unicorn and all :P

Comment: This started happening again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/duplicate-questions-show-up-as-closed-in-search-results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This adds a bit of query load to the search page (not heavy load, but does affect load time) to search results.  However, we can make that happens *only* for closed questions - so it'll go out next deploy.  The same cases we currently show `[duplicate]` elsewhere, will be echoed in `/search` after the next build.