# Ways to retract my upvote on Moderator Election Question Collection

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, election, locked-votes

Now, Meta have a topic to collect questions for moderator election: [2014 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

In the explanation part, there is following statement:

> Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions

Each day, new questions are added and since there is a bunch of question there, I read and then upvote if I consider that question must be within the list.

Good questions posted earlier have higher votes as one of them belongs to me, as expected. Then I see a newly posted question which ,IMO, is one of the best questions on tis page and **should** be asked. But since it was posted lately, it have a lower score and the possibility of reaching top 8 do not seem possible.

I know top 8 is not guaranteed to be asked, but I wish not to up-vote some answers posted earlier since if there is 8 slot for questions (at most), then I wish that question must be in the list instead of some other ones.

Downvoting high scored questions is not logical since they are *good* questions too and downvoting do not seem fair to me. Just, if I had a chance to re-select, I would vote for the newly posted one, not high-scored one

You can not retract your vote after some time. But I guess that can be changed since, like being able to change your vote during the election phase, people may retract their votes to carry the question they liked to the top 8 through the question selection phase.

Comment: It's CW so I guess you could always make (and possibly then undo) a trivial edit to the answer to unlock your vote.

Comment: Ah, thanks @MartinSmith, but is it the right way to go for that situation? If yes, then you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Technically, votes can be unlocked on a regular (say daily) basis by [touching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564/165773) all the answers.

Such a *mass-touch* would better be done by a community manager, or SE developer, or by [Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-user/info) to clearly indicate that this is not a personal thing.

It can even preserve an existing order in the *active* tab if "touching edits" are performed in the order from least recently to most recently active answer.

<sub>Note during such an update, question would better be temporarily [locked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/locked/info), to prevent concurrent modifications. Otherwise, "touch loop" would unfairly bury in an *active* tab new answers and edits that may occur in the middle of it.</sub>

Comment: But that do not seem to be a practical solution... Touching 60+ is hard if this is done by real moderator. Community user may touch them every x hours so votes would be unlocked anytime.

Comment: @FallenAngel yeah auto-touching by Community user would be my preferred way, too. I think that way it would look most accurate in answers revision histories