# What does it mean when an edit has the description "[Edit removed during grace period]"?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

Recently I came across a few edits on the formatting sandbox with the description "[Edit removed during grace period]".

[image]

It definitely wasn't made within the 5 minute grace period. What does it mean?

Comment: Related, unsure if dupe because Sandbox behaves funnily: [Undone edits disappear from revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564/398063)

Comment: @Jenayah I think that's talking about something different. In this case, it's still showing the edit in the revision history, but not what the edit actually changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply a null edit. If a user has added any word or sentence into a question or answer and removes (or vice versa) that without a rollback during the 5 minute grace period, then the system shows no change in the revisions and just shows [Edit removed during grace period]. There will be two consecutive revisions with some content.

I reproduced that in [an answer to sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/319769/4).

The same happened with the revisions 251 and other few [Edit removed during grace period] revisions shown in Formatting Sandbox question.